# How to bind a ButtonAssist CornerRadius Value of Material Design from a source

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, material-design-in-xaml

I'm using C# WPF with Material Design .

**What I need :**

I'm trying to set `CornerRadius` of `ButtonAssist` for any `Button` in my project.

**Problem:**

I can't set this property from `Application.Resources`.

My XAML :

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MaterialDesignation"
    xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
    x:Class="MaterialDesignation.MainWindow"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.Resources>
    
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <!--I Want to Set Radius For All Buttons in My Projects like blow line ↓-->
    <Button Content="Button" materialDesign:ButtonAssist.CornerRadius="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="71,260,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="237" Height="85" Background="#FF038BEA" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"/>

    
    <Button Content="Button" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=Gerdy}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="410,129,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="237" Height="85" Background="#FF038BEA" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"/>
    <Button Content="Button" materialDesign:ButtonAssist.CornerRadius="{Binding Gerdy}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="71,129,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="237" Height="85" Background="#FF038BEA" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"/>

</Grid>
```

**My App.xaml :**

```
<Application x:Class="MaterialDesignation.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
          xmlns:clr="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MaterialDesignation"
         xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        
        <Style x:Key="Gerdy" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Style.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Setter Property="materialDesign:ButtonAssist.CornerRadius" Value="30" />
                </Style>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>

        <clr:Byte x:Key="GerdyAsByte">30</clr:Byte>

        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Light.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.DeepPurple.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.Lime.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Here is my full WPF project link :
https://ufile.io/gt5dcjzh

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom *implicit* style (without `x:Key`) for `Button` that is based on the MaterialDesign styles and only changes the `CornerRadius` of the `ButtonAssist`. It will be applied automatically to all `Button`s in scope.

Create a separate resource dictionary for your button style, so it can be added after the resource dictionaries of MaterialDesign, otherwise they will override your style instead you overriding their default style. Please also be aware that local values will always override the values from the style.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes">
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
      <Setter Property="materialDesign:ButtonAssist.CornerRadius" Value="30" />
   </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then add them to the `MergedDictionaries` *after* the MaterialDesign resource dictionaries.

```
<Application x:Class="MaterialDesignation.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
              xmlns:clr="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MaterialDesignation"
             xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>

           <clr:Byte x:Key="GerdyAsByte">30</clr:Byte>

            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
               <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Light.xaml" />
               <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
               <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.DeepPurple.xaml" />
               <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.Lime.xaml" />
               <ResourceDictionary Source="CustomButtonStyles.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```